How to pass image URL and Heading into button link using Javascript / jQuery
Is there any way to pass image URL and Heading into button link using Javascript / jQuery?
For example, I have the following code:
<div class="product-item">
    <img src="image1.jpg" arc="Image 1">
    <h3>Product Title 1</h3>
    <div class="button">
        Send Inquiry
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-item">
    <img src="image2.jpg" arc="Image 2">
    <h3>Product Title 2</h3>
    <div class="button">
        Send Inquiry
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-item">
    <img src="image3.jpg" arc="Image 3">
    <h3>Product Title 3</h3>
    <div class="button">
        Send Inquiry
    </div>
</div>


I want to get the final result as:
<div class="product-item">
    <img src="image1.jpg" arc="Image 1">
    <h3>Product Title 1</h3>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="/inquiry?image=image1.jpg&title=Product Title 1">Send Inquiry</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-item">
    <img src="image2.jpg" arc="Image 2">
    <h3>Product Title 2</h3>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="/inquiry?image=image2.jpg&title=Product Title 2">Send Inquiry</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-item">
    <img src="image3.jpg" arc="Image 1">
    <h3>Product Title 3</h3>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="/inquiry/?image=image3.jpg&title=Product Title 3">Send Inquiry</a>
    </div>
</div>

Thank you so much!
Currently I can only edit each button link manually, but I have a lot of pages that need such links.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

What have you tried so far and what specifically goes wrong? [ask]

What is arc attribute used for?

Maybe you can try this code. First you need to get all buttons and do each loop, then get image sibling of current button to get image src, and also get product title, and then replace button content with a tag.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="product-item">
        <img src="image1.jpg" arc="Image 1">
        <h3>Product Title 1</h3>
        <div class="button">
            Send Inquiry
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="product-item">
        <img src="image2.jpg" arc="Image 2">
        <h3>Product Title 2</h3>
        <div class="button">
            Send Inquiry
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="product-item">
        <img src="image3.jpg" arc="Image 3">
        <h3>Product Title 3</h3>
        <div class="button">
            Send Inquiry
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.button').each((index, element)=>{

                const buttonText = $(element).text();
                const image = $(element).siblings('img').eq(0).attr('src');
                const title = $(element).siblings('h3').text();

                const url = `/inquiry?image=${image}&title=${title}`;

                $(element).html(`<a href="${url}">${buttonText}</a>`)
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>

